# Validation Exceptions not serialized when using IReturnVoid interface

Tags: servicestack

I am facing a problem when trying ServiceStack Validation feature. If my request DTOs inherits IReturnVoid interface the exception type is WebException but if i change IReturnVoid to IReturn than i can catch WebServiceException and my validation error's are serialized. Is this bug or any logic behind it ?
If so i will have to change all my put and delete requests to return int instead of void.
Thank you.

Comment: Update : Also when using IReturn<int> on http verb Delete than error is not serialized with the new api. If i change to IReturn<ResponseStatus> ( a class that holds only ResponseStatus propery ) than Delete request validation error are also serialized.

Comment: Did you figure something out about this issue?